# check the format of a date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date input that requires the user to enter the date in the following format: DD-MM-YYYY - It is then converted to YYYY-MM-DD

I want to perform a check to see whether they are entering the correct format. i.e. if anything else is entered other than DD-MM-YYYY then it should produce an error message

Im currently using the following

```
                    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);

                    if(checkdate($m, $d, $y)){

                    }else{
                        die("The date was in the wrong format");
                    }
```

I have tried putting the code that follows this inside the if statement, aswell as not including the else at all - but it does not work. Any suggestions on what i can try? Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking the user to enter *DD-MM-YYYY*, but your `list()` call expects the `explode()` order as *YYYY-MM-DD*.

Update your code to with:

```
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

just reverse the statement:

```
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date);
if(!checkdate($m, $d, $y)){
    die("The date was in the wrong format");
}
// your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

try these

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/05/date-format-validation-php.html

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/date-validation.php

better to  validate first in client side using js then you can do php validtaion .

why the page should submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = '31-05-2011';

$ts = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $in);

$out = date_format($ts, 'd-m-Y');

if ($in === $out) {
   ... it's correctly formatted
}
```

Note that this won't catch mistakes such as saying '03-04-11' for March 4th 2011, when the user really mean 11th April, 2003.